# How to add users with a specific role to products in magento

Tags: magento, catalog

I am having a set of users with custom resource access

When i add a product to my catalog i want this users to be shown in a drop down and admin can assign one user to each product

How to achieve this?

does magento have build in functionality for this.

If it does not have which is the optimum way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add an attribute to the product entity with a setup script. Your attribute will need a custom `source_model` which reads admin user information and builds a collection based on role assignment.

Comment: It took a while to come back to this as i was busy with some other tasks. Worked thanks